# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.(FLUTTER)

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

Hey guys I jut wanted to debug a recent project, but when I tried it, I got an error.

**This is the error:**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A202F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I searched the internet and found that it could be related to a flutter update.

**Could that be?**

**And what is the solution for this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
flutter upgrade
```

then:

```
flutter run -v
```

It may help you.