# Flutter: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

Since the last update of Android Studio (today is 23th of August 2020), each time I create a new flutter project I can't run it. Even if I do not modify a line of code and only create a blank new project then run it.

All my previous flutter project can be run in my VD without any problem. But I can't work on new projects because of this build failure.

1. I emptied cache using the menu 'File/Invalidate Caches / Restart ...'
2. I upgraded Flutter using "flutter upgrade --force' then 'flutter run -v' like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739578/failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-flutter) but it did not work for me.

I learn flutter via courses online but I don't know what to do to solve this problem.
Do you have a solution ?
Thank you

Here is what happens in the console (with a new flutter application project):

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-hi\values-hi.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-de\values-de.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-lo\values-lo.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-pt\values-pt.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-lt\values-lt.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-hr\values-hr.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\androidstudio\proj\boule_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-lv\values-lv.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try to uninstall and to do a new and fresh install. This error usually refers to changes made in source files without updating references or any other resources the compiler is expecting. There are many errors coming from this new flutter version after upgraded.

Comment: Thank you, I uninstalled Android Studio but the directory "Android Studio" in c:\programme files was still there containing a jre directory, so I renamed it to Android Studio-old. Then, I downloaded the last version of Android Studio from the official website, then created a new flutter project and ran it but the problem is  still here with the same errors.... :/

Comment: I also try to build the new flutter application project using VS Code, but I had the same messages

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49438

Answer (score -1):

Delete the androidstudio folder from the C:\Users\Steeve\Documents\Flutter\ directory.